# How to start Atom or VSCode natively installed on Windows from within WSL (Ubuntu)?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Atom editor natively on Windows 10 by downloading an running the installer. Now I start WSL Ubuntu distro and want to start Atom (atom-editor) from there with the command `atom .` or VSCode (visual-studio-code) with the command `code .`

Atom starts, but not in the directory where the command was executed, instead it shows files from `C:\\Windows`. Moreover Ubuntu WSL terminal shows following error message:

```
atom .
grep: /etc/wsl.conf: No such file or directory
"\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\wlad\projects\udemy\flask-bootcamp\Flask-Bootcamp-master"
CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
UNC-Pfade werden nicht unterstützt.
Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.
```

Sorry it's German localized but it says something like `UNC-paths are not supported`

(haven't tested VSCode yet)

**So how can I use Atom or VSCode editor installed on Windows 10 from within WSL?**

** **UPDATE** **
As of today (April 2020) there is a much better way to use VSCode on Windows w/ WSL, VirtualMachines (VM) and even Containers. Check out [remote-development plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) for VSCode.

Comment: helpful --> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/

Comment: run `explorer.exe .` in WSL will open the current folder in Windows Explorer. From there you can use right-click context menu to open files/directories in VSCode or Atom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Known issues" section of the [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) @Wlad mentioned, there states

> Accessing Linux files is treated the same as accessing a network resource, and any rules for accessing network resources will still apply e.g: When using CMD, cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home will not work (as CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories), however copy \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\somefile.txt C:\dev\ will work

So as Atom may use `cmd.exe` to launch itself from the command line (maybe some batch file), and given the fact that `cmd.exe` cannot open network resources as current directory (which WSL directory is treated as), there came the failure as you attempted to launch Atom from WSL shell.

Actually, in VS Code there is a better solution to launch VS Code directly from the WSL shell: `VS Code Remote`.

You can take the following steps to enable VS Code to be directly launched from WSL shell：

1. Install the extension [`Remote - WSL`](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/wsl) to VS Code on the Windows side;
2. Then when you type `code .` in your WSL shell, VS Code Remote Server will be automatically installed, and VS Code will soon launch.

By using `VS Code Remote`, you can not only open the directory in VS Code, but can also be benefited in many other aspects: for example, you can use the WSL shell as the integrated shell in VS Code and run programs in WSL directly from VS Code.

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) is the official doc for `VS Code Remote - WSL`.

Comment: I think in the meanwhile things got better and at least VS Code should work out of the box. Haven't tried with Atom yet, though. Cause I feel like I want to go back to a Linux OS anyway :)

Answer (score 7):

I created a short script to handle the three atom commands I use most (I use Ubuntu with WSL):

1. `atom`
2. `atom .`
3. `atom RELATIVE_PATH_FILE`

This script is not optimized, and I'm sure many people will find edge cases, but it gets the job done for me. To use it, simply placed it in `~/.local/bin/atom` and make it executable by running `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/atom`. You may need to restart your shell for `~/.local/bin` to be added to your path. In order to simplify things a bit, I mapped the WSL network drive for my ubuntu installation to `U:`, so you'll either want to do the same or modify the script accordingly on line 9.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  pushd /mnt/c > /dev/null
  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "atom"
else
  [[ $1 = "." ]] && path=$(pwd) || path=$(realpath $1)

  winPath=$(echo "U:$path" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g')

  pushd /mnt/c > /dev/null
  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "atom $winPath"
fi

popd > /dev/null
```

The script performs a few simple steps. First, if there is no command line argument, it simply calls atom using `cmd.exe` without arguments. If the command line argument is `.`, it gets the path to the current directory, otherwise, it gets the absolute path to the given file using `realpath`. The path is converted from POSIX to Windows format using `sed` before calling atom using `cmd.exe` as before, but with the path argument.

The `pushd` and `popd` commands are just there to get rid of the annoying warning message about UNC paths not being supported:

```
...
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory
```

Comment: This was a good start to resolving my issue but not completely. This seems to open a file with the folder name if I use `.` as the parameter. Any thoughts on resolving this?

Comment: As @tom-klino commented below, this happens if the U drive is not yet mounted (usually at startup). I'm sure there is a more permanent solution, but to quickly mount the drive, launch WSL first, then browse to the U: drive from File Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The script in Eduardo's answer is a great approach, but didn't allow to open multiple directories/repos at once (e.g. `atom terraform-modules terraform-repo`), which I do often.

The following is my twist on it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

winPathPrefix="U:"

function convertToWinPath() {
  echo "${winPathPrefix}$(realpath ${1})" | sed -e 's/\//\\/g'
}

declare -a atomCmd=(/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "atom")

for path in "$@"; do
  atomCmd+=($(convertToWinPath ${path}))
done

${atomCmd[@]} 2>/dev/null
```

That is entirely based on Eduardo's script and should allow a more general use case

Comment: This was a good adjustment! I added a note to Eduardo's as well, for some reason when I use "." as the parameter it seems to open the directory as a file instead of add the directory to Atom. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I encountered this as well, it happens if the U drive is not yet mounted (it gets a path that doesn't exist and interprets it as a file that needs to be created). I just open a file browser on U once and that should be enough until the next restart. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to run Atom from WSL got me here but unfortunately the accepted answer does not mention atom and the other atom related workarounds don't work anymore.

In case someone googles the question and ends up here. Here's an actual workaround (It will break in new Atom updates).

- Add the following path path in the windows enviroments: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\atom\app-{version}\` (at the time of this post the version is `1.60.0` so `app-1.60.0`.

  - Use the path mentioned above as the default path contains a bash executable that will be run fail to run in wsl.
  - Here's where it will break in future updates. The fix is to update the env in windows to the new path since the folder where the exe is located will change to match atom's version.
- Add the following in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

  - Important to be added in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` as making a separate script in `/usr/bin` will always make atom to open in the `C:/Windows` folder.

```
function _atom () { exec nohup atom.exe "$@" &> /dev/null & } # Do not output in terminal and do not block the terminal. Also send the command arguments to atom.

alias atom="_atom"
```

- Open a new wsl terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script to open atom with and without files from WSL2. It can handle any number (including 0) of file arguments, on any drive. Both relative and absolute paths are supported, but it can't handle path name containing .. or ~. Pointing atom to a director also works as expected. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
atom_cmd="/mnt/c/Users/`whoami`/AppData/Local/atom/atom.exe"
for i in "$@"; do
if [[ $i == /mnt* ]]; then 
    linPath="$i" #for absolute file paths
else 
    linPath="`pwd`/$i" #for relative file paths
fi
if [[ $linPath == *".."* || $linPath != "/mnt"* || $i == "/home"* ]] ; then
    echo "atom script is unacceptable file path $linPath"
    continue 1
fi
winPath="\""`echo $linPath | sed -e 's|\/mnt\/\([a-z]\)|\u\1:|' -e 's:\/:\\\\:g'`""
atom_cmd="$atom_cmd $winPath\""
done
unset linPath
unset winPath
echo "command:" "$atom_cmd"
eval "$atom_cmd"
unset atom_cmd
```

(I'm sure there are things to improve about this, like edge cases and better use of language features. I'd welcome suggestions.)

Answer (score -3):

this can be a little bit outdated but you can simply run a powershell and use:

```
wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 //In my case ubuntu
```

This should open a ubuntu session or whatever wsl you have set on your own.

A little bit nooby on this but trying to help. =)